# How can I pass a multi-line variable to a docker container?

Tags: docker, yaml, docker-compose

According to [this comment,](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12997#issuecomment-204580515) multi-line variables are supported with `docker compose`:

```
environment:
  KEY: |-
    line1
    line2
```

However, when I execute `echo $KEY` in the container, it has replaced the newline with spaces:

`line1 line2`

Am I missing something? My docker version is 1.12.1.

Comment: The `echo` always does that under Linux/Unix if you don't use double-quotes on the environment variable. That is why you should always, use quotes around them (there are many posts on the U&L site relating to this, and this has nothing to do with using YAML: the value for the mapping entry with key `KEY` certainly has a newline)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The YAML syntax is correct. The shell command wasn't:

`echo "$KEY"`

prints the string with newlines.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem a couple of days  ago and solved it via:

```
KEY: "line1\nline2"
```

Hope that helps in your case as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The result is still written on one line (as above).

Comment: Meh, even when wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Yes ............ Wait ... no! You're a genius! :-) Do you want to add it to your answer for future reference? Actually my syntax above worked as well when using `echo "$KEY"`.

Comment: @giraff hehe .. You're welcome :) I wrapped it already in quotes or what do you mean? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `>` this solution works pretty well if you need to have a json in your env variables. There are many ways to have a [multiline strings in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines).

```
version: '2'
services:
  catalog-api-autoscaling:
    image: company.it/project/catalog-api-autoscaling:latest
    container_name: api-autoscaling
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
        CONFIG_ABC: >
          {
            "database": {
               "catalog": {
                   "credentials": {
                       "username": "scott",
                       "password": "tiger",
                       "datbase": "catalog",
                       "host": "gn.dmfkd.lan"
                    }
                }
            }
          }
        CONFIG_DEF: >
          {
            "urlRegex": "/.*",
            "script": {
              "scriptPath": "example-python-app.py"
            },
            "runtime": "python27",
            "threadsafe": true,
          }
```